# addEventListener: "Argument types do not match parameters"

Tags: webstorm

I've had this code for a while but just today I noticed this:

[image]

I'm not sure what I would have changed that could have caused this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please vote for [WEB-30082](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-30082) to be notified on any progress with it

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Creating an array from the event helped me fix it.

Comment: Maybe put the code in rather than a link to an image so it's easier to see straight up